# How are doubles/floats rounded when the "true" result is not representable accurately enough?

Tags: floating-point, language-agnostic

I know floating point numbers are inaccurate. However my question is to which "next" number the result is rounded.

Is it the next higher one? The next lower one? Is it the closest one?

My guess is that it's a question of what happens to the mantissa, but I'm not sure if it's just truncated no matter what or if it depends on whether the result is created "from below" (e.g. sums) or "from above" (e.g. differences).

Or is it even easier and it's purely arbitrary and only depending on the compiler/architecture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very likely that your compilation platform uses IEEE 754.

For the basic operations, +, -, *, /, rounding is not arbitrary. IEEE 754 defines several [rounding modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Rounding_rules). The default mode if you did not explicitly set one is to round the result to the nearest representable value (“Round to nearest, ties to even”). Such is the care for detail in IEEE 754 that a rule describes what to do when the result is equally close to two candidate representable values.

For more complex functions, for instance sine, it depends on the implementation. The least precise implementations might even produce a result that isn't any of the two closest representable values to the real result!

David Golberg's “What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic” [article](http://www.itu.dk/~sestoft/bachelor/IEEE754_article.pdf) is often recommended willy-nilly on this site anytime floating-point comes up, but in this case, it sounds like you might like to read it.

Answer (score 1):

This is implementation-dependent, but most implementations that follow the IEEE 754 standard have means to select one of several rounding options.

The default mode is rounding to the nearest representable number, and in case of a tie, round to the even number (i.e. the one with the least significant bit equals zero).

See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754 for more.